# How to install cocos2d 2.0 beta?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

http://i44.tinypic.com/2qb5dl0.jpg

I get all these errors after running the install-templates.sh. I only get them when compiling for device, simulator runs without any errors (the warnings remain though).
Why and how do i fix this? So frustrating..

Worth mentioning is that i edited the install-remplates.sh so i could run it as root, that wasnt recommended but it wouldnt work otherwise. (didnt get permission to create folders and such..). Im running Lion, that might be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall the templates without sudo, using the unmodified template installer script like so:

```
./install-templates.sh -f -u
```

This will install the templates in the user's Library folder which is the recommended way.

If this fails with errory, you most likely have older templates installed which you've installed with sudo. In that case the templates script won't allow you to overwrite them in the user folder without using sudo, while the script itself doesn't allow you to install the cocos2d templates to the user folder with sudo anymore.

To fix that, simply delete the old (installed with sudo) templates first by deleting this folder:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d
```

In a couple weeks I'll have cocos2d 2.0 integrated in [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com). From then on you can just run the Kobold2D package installer and start working.